# issue with slow insertion sort at specified index

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort, insertion

I'm writing an insertion sort program however with my current implementation it takes around 9.470 sec seconds when "n" is 40,000. I was wondering if theirs a way to tighten this up (faster version of swap?) I'm open to any and all suggestions and appreciate the help.

(code below)

```
public void insertionSort(ArrayList<String> data, int firstIndex, int numberToSort) {
    for (int i = 1; i < numberToSort; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (data.get((2 * firstIndex) + i).compareTo(data.get(firstIndex + j)) < 0)
                Collections.swap(data, firstIndex + i, firstIndex + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's*
spelling*

Comment: Don't use a quadratic algorithm for large lists.

Comment: @AndyTurner do you have a suggestion to refactor the two loops to .. something?
or, rather, is the basis of the method just slow and I should start anew.

Comment: You can't go directly from your algorithm to an O(n log n) one; you should look on a search engine of your choice to find example implementations. Compare the speed of your implementation to `Collections.sort(data.subList(i, i + num))` to see how much faster it is.

Comment: BTW, why `2 * firstIndex + i`? Why not just `firstIndex + i`?

Comment: I see, perhaps rethinking my approach is needed then. In regards to the 2*, My teacher advised it.

Comment: You could replace the swaps with a shift (rotate) of a sub-array. Take a look at the second pseudo-code example in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm_for_insertion_sort) .